# CFSelect bind issue in ColdBox environment

Tags: coldfusion, bind, cfml, coldbox

I'm having an issue with bindings, so time to refer to the experts.

I have a cfselect that binds to a cfc.

```
 <cfselect name="events" id="events" selected="#form.event_id#" 
 bind="cfc:feat.models.dynform.getEventsByGroup({groups})" display="event_name" 
 value="nd_event_id" queryPosition="below">
```

Which works well in my local environment, defined as `"feat"` under my local `/www` directory. My issue is when I move it to the dev server, which I believed to be in `"beat"`, ie:

```
 bind="cfc:beat.models.dynform.getEventsByGroup({groups})"
```

I receive the error "model not found", event though the model is there. I assume this is because the dev server is arranged differently than my local one. Is there a clue in the ColdBox config as to where this should point?

I also attempted to change the bind to call the model (so I wouldn't have to use different markup than my local) by placing the model in the `rc` collection:

```
 bind="cfc:#rc.dynformservice#.getEventsByGroup({groups})"
```

However, I get an error "cannot cast complex datatypes as string".

Any suggestions? I'm in your debt for any help.

Comment: What is rc.dynformservice?  .

Comment: a request collection in the coldbox handler ex: function reconcile(event, rc, prc){
rc.dynformservice=getmodel("dynform");

Comment: sounds like a complex data type to me.

Comment: and it was, posting answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coldbox way of passing in a path is

```
 cfc:#getSetting('AppMapping')#.model.dynform...
```